# How to Delete Swap vimrc file and PLuginInstall not a command in ArchLinux

Tags: linux, vim, archlinux

not an editor command: PluginInstall

As i am trying to setup VIM for python and tried to setup vim vundle, but it showed me few errors:

1. not an editor command: PluginInstall
2. In the second error i got that i have to delete swap file, but i am unable to do so

Comment: What are your trying to do? What are the exact steps you took? Also provide the *exact* error messages you got. Please [edit] and add the missing information so others can reproduce your problem.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://vi.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

- To delete the swap file, type this in the terminal: `vim -r .vimrc`.

It will then ask you if you would like to delete the swap file.

- After you are done with this, close your vimrc file and run this in your terminal.

`git clone https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/plugin/Vundle.vim`